# Performance tradeoff in breaking a long formula in pieces and storing them with temporary variables

Tags: c++, c

I have a long equation which I can easily write in multiple lines using `\`. However, same can be achieved using the following which I feel is better in terms of readability.

```
double func(...){
double const term1 = ...;
double const term2 = ...;
double const term3 = ...;

double const long_eqn = term1 + term2 + term3;
return long_eqn;
}
```

Can someone throw some light about pros and cons between these two methods? Will there be performance degradation due to the second method?

This is for a hpc code where could spend most time doing these computations. Let's assume `-O3` would be the flag used for the build.

Comment: If you have not already, familiarize yourself with the [As-if Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). The compiler as allowed to do anything it wants to your code to improve efficiency so long as it does not deviate from the behaviour described by the code (with copy elision being a notable exception where it CAN change the behaviour).

Comment: End result, crank up the optimizer and it shouldn't matter a bit how you break down the equation, so go with readability and then profile. If the more readable code does have an impact, only then should you go for less readable, profiling all the way to make sure that the changes really do make things better.

Comment: Aside: You don't need to use `\\` to continue multi-line statements in C. This is not a shell script - linefeeds have no significance. The parser ignores whitespace.

Comment: Exception to above Aside: macro definitions must be all one line and often do use \ when they get lengthy.

Comment: Your future self will thank you if you break your long equation(s) up into smaller terms.  It makes debugging easier, aids readability and, in optimised builds, will almost certainly not impact performance.

Comment: @PaulSanders: If you can detail your comment with enough source/examples, I can accept it as answer.

Comment: The truth is in the assembly language.  Print out the assembly language of the long statement, and save.  Break the long statement into smaller ones.  Print out the assembly language.  Compare the two.  IMHO, the compiler has to perform all the steps anyway, so why not help the compiler?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your code correct then optimize for readability.  Prefer even more descriptive variables names than `term`. Ensure you use optimization settings for your compiler (gcc -O2 or -O3 to start with).  If you are worried about performance profile your code. Usually, it's the surprising result that are most interesting.